# Flask app deployment with lighttpd results in error

Tags: python, flask, webserver, wsgi, lighttpd

I'm trying to deploy my flask app with lighttpd and fastcgi on a Raspberry Pi. Unfortunately I can not get it to work. Here my procedure:

- I installed lighttpd with `sudo apt install lighttpd`
- I installed flup with `pip install flup`

created /var/www/demoapp/hello.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

created /var/www/demoapp/hello.fcgi

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
from hello import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WSGIServer(app).run()
```

added the follwoing to /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf

```
fastcgi.server = ("/hello.fcgi" => ((
   "socket" => "/tmp/hello-fcgi.sock",
   "bin-path" => "/var/www/demoapp/hello.fcgi",
   "check-local" => "disable",
   "max-procs" => 1
)))

alias.url += (
   "/static" => "/var/www/demoapp/static"
)

url.rewrite-once = (
   "^(/static($|/.*))$" => "$1",
   "^(/.*)$" => "/hello.fcgi$1"
)
```

To reload the configuration the webserver is restarted with `sudo /etc/init.d/lighttpd restart`

Then I expect that I can access the app under `raspberrypi.local/static` I just get a `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` by Chrome.

Can you spot something that is wrong in my procedure? Did I miss something?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

After a rewrite, lighttpd internally reprocesses the request so the rewrite to remove the "/static" prefix WILL NOT MATCH the alias for the "/static" prefix, since the "/static" prefix no longer exists after the rewrite.

```
if $HTTP["url] !~ "^/static($|/)" {
    url.rewrite-once = (
       "^/hello.fcgi" => "",
       "^(/.*)$" => "/hello.fcgi$1"
    )
}
```